# Find several groups of ocurrences in String with regex Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a String like this:

```
val rawData = "askljdld<a>content to extract</a>lkdsjkdj<a>more content to extract</a>sdkdljk
```

and I want to extract the content between the tags `<a>`

I've tried this, but the end part of the regex is not working as I expected:

```
val regex = "<a>(.*)</a>".r
for(m <- regex.findAllIn(rawData)){
      println(m)
    }
```

the output is:

```
<a>content to extract</a>lkdsjkdj<a>more content to extract</a>
```

I understand what's happening: the regex finds the first `<a>` and the last `</a>`.
How can I have an iterator with the two entries?

```
<a>content to extract</a>
<a>more content to extract</a>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use the lazy operator `*?`

Answer (score 1):

All is very simple: `"<a>(.*?)</a>"`

`.*?` - means `anything until something`. In your case until `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not the right one. You should use `<a>(.*?)</a>` instead

```
val rawData = "askljdld<a>content to extract</a>lkdsjkdj<a>more content to extract</a>sdkdljk"

val regex = "<a>(.*?)</a>".r

regex.findAllIn(rawData).foreach(println)
```